# haskell create new operator, and control error

Tags: function, haskell, types, operation

I have the following structure:

Terra [['0','1','0','1'],['0','1','0','1'],['1','0','G','1']]

and de function:

```
esTerra:: Taulell -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
esTerra t (u,d) = 
    case t!!!u!!!d of
        Left e -> False
        Right p -> True


(!!!) :: [a] -> Int -> Either Bool a 
xs !!! n | n < 0 = Left False   -- error Exception: Prelude.!!:...
[] !!! _ = Left False           -- error Exception: Prelude.!!:...
(x:_) !!! 0 = Right x
(_:xs) !!! n = xs!!!(n-1)
```

the function !!! is equal the operation !! but when you have to return an error message returns False

but return error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
            with actual type ‘Either Bool [Char]’
In the first argument of ‘(!!!)’, namely ‘t !!! u’
In the expression: t !!! u !!! d
In the expression:
  case t !!! u !!! d of {
    Left e -> False
    Right p -> True }
```

Because?

Thank's

Comment: on a side note - your `Either Bool a` is never using `Left True` therefore this is equivalent to using a `Maybe a`, if your choice is an `Either` I'd recommend using `Either String` and using the `Left` for `Left "nice descriptive error message"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what `Taulell` is, let's guess `Taulell = [[a]]` for some `a`.

We have

```
t :: [[a]]  -- Taulell
u :: Int
d :: Int
```

hence

```
t !!! u :: Either Bool [a]
```

Then we write

```
(t !!! u) !!! d
```

but here the leftmost argument is not a list, it's an `Either Bool [a]`. Hence a type error arises.

Instead, we could try, e.g.

```
case t !!! u of
   Left b -> ...
   Right l -> case l !!! d of
                 Left c  -> ...
                 Rigth w -> ...
```

Comment: @MercedesCabreraTorres: you should _understand_ how it's done step by step, but that's not how you'd do it in a large-scale project. When have a nesting of not two but, say, _eight_ possibly-failing computations, then giving each one its own `case` would be very awkward indeed. Fortunately, the monad instance takes this burden from us!

Answer (score 1):

`!!!` needs a list as its left argument, but for a nested list it does not give a simple list as the result. It gives an `Either Bool [a]` as the result.

You can't use that again as the argument to `!!!`, but you can easily enough *apply* `!!!` to the `Either`-contained list:

```
esTerra:: Taulell -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
esTerra t (u,d) = 
    case t!!!u >>= (!!!d) of
        Left e -> False
        Right p -> True
```

Here, I've used the monadic bind operator [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html#v:-62--62--61-) to combine two possibly-failing lookups into one, which will succeed only if *both* lookups do. This is equivalent to *twice* explicitly unwrapping the `Either` structure with a `case` construct, [as shown by chi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36413756/745903).

Comment: then >> = is the equivalent of 
 Left b -> ...
 Right l -> case l !!! d of .... no? thank's

Comment: Yes, in this case it is equivalent. But the monadic bind is far more general, it also works for types completely unlike `Either`!